# Grid mode on home page - Magento

Tags: magento-1.5, magento-1.6, magento-1.7, magento

I just developed a store, and everytime you add a new item, it shows on the home page. That's perfect! But the thing is that it shows the products on list mode, and I want to use grid mode.

I specified on System->Configuration->Catalog the only grid mode, but it works when I show the catalog, but when I go to home page it shows the products on list mode.

I also have on my Home page this code inside:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" num_products="6" template="catalog/random.phtml"}}
```

but if I change it manually to product_grid it doesn't work. I guess maybe is because I have to change it manually on the code somewhere, not on CMS, but I don't know where...

Any help will be thanked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure, but try:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" mode="grid" num_products="6" template="catalog/random.phtml"}
```

Comment: I guess it is dependent on the template you use, namely catalog/random.phtml. Maybe this displays a list instead of a grid?

Comment: yes, that's it. I created a new template on which I specify the grid or list mode. And it works. Thanks!